# Bugsense on Android service

Tags: android, android-service, bugsense

Following Bugsense docs I've found that I need to add this code on Service onCreate:

`BugSenseHandler.setup(context, "MY_API_KEY");`

What it is that `context` variable? Do I need to pass main Activity reference to service constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context` is your main activity or your service. Initialize BugSense calling `BugSenseHandler.setup()` with `this`.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        BugSenseHandler.setup(this, "MY_API_KEY");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I am asking for. I'm asking about how to initialize bugsense on a Service.

Comment: It's the same. Updated answer with service example.

Answer (score 0):

The new API states this:

```
BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(MyService.this, "MY_API_KEY");
```

But pretty much the same as what jelies said [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772159/468360)

Don't forget about these as well:

Whenever you want to explicitly start the session, you can use the startSession method at the onStart method of your activity, as follows:

```
BugSenseHandler.startSession(MyService.this);
```

Whenever you want to close the session, you can use the closeSession method as follows:

```
BugSenseHandler.closeSession(MyService.this)
```

If you want to manually flush all the saved data, use the BugSenseHandler.flush(Context) method:

```
BugSenseHandler.flush(MyService.this);
```

Full doc for Bugsense is here: https://www.bugsense.com/docs/android 
You can apply this same logic to the service.

Comment: Where do I put "BugSenseHandler.flush(MyService.this);" in the code?  Oncreate?

Comment: It would be more used in between major events so you can easily see an events start to easily troubleshoot.